# How to avoid re login in facebook using API php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an web application to sync users contacts from various social networks. Here the user need to login with their login details. Once they logged into the web app they can add accounts like facebook, google plus etc. Once they added thier various accounts they can see all their contacts/friends in this app.

For example once a user added his facebook account he can see all his facebook contacts in this web app, to do so the user need to login facebook and allow the app to access the user's public information. When the user login next time in this app his facebook contacts already added should be needed to be there, and the user should not need to re login in facebook to see his contacts. How can I accomplish this? How can I authenticate the user automatically once the user login to web app?

Comment: you could save the FB access tokens to database and later use it to avoid re-login..!

Comment: Sudhir: How can I use this FB access tokens for authentication?